# How does this font pair with this logo? Specifically its curves/softness?

Tags: logo, typography, critique

I'm looking for some feedback on the typography of this logo.  Specifically, assuming the logo itself stays the same, how does the font choice and typography pair with it?

e.g. Are the E's too sharp, or is the curve of the P too round?  Where does this font fit the logo well or poorly?

Thank you!

[image: Powderhouse Studios Logo + Mark]

Comment: Agree with Scott that the typeface is bad. So you will want to look at alternatives. When you do - and maybe present another version here - consider the arrangement of the two words: Looks rather unusual for a graph plus words; the word marks are often "aligned" rather than "flush left". Look at many other logos and consider tweaking the font size of "STUDIOS" or maybe centering...

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're asking for *opinion* so here's mine.....

That typeface is absolutely ***dreadful***.

- The uneven curves of the P and R serve as a magnet for the eye....
- The odd, illogical, tails on the U and T are equally magnetic...
- The kerning between the POW, the HOU, and the IOS are clearly greater than the rest of the pairs.

In short, one doesn't so much as "read" the type as bounce back and forth between the magnetic qualities resulting in a *very* "jagged" or "disruptive" viewing experience.

How the type relates to the symbol above it is irrelevant. The type is so awful it diminishes the entire mark completely.

Again.. my *opinion* since you asked.